# System keeps using older python version (3.8) after upgrading to Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: upgrade, python, 21.04

I just upgraded my Ubuntu yesterday to 21.04 from 20.10. There was a warning prompt shown in the installation (can't remember what it was). I just proceeded to install and it worked fine.

But later when I started to use python, (pip, git, etc). I was getting the error `/usr/bin/env: ‘python3.8’: No such file or directory`. I later deleted the python3.8 folder in `~/.local/lib` since it wasn't needed anymore thinking it'll fix it. But it didn't and now none of these critical programs work.

Python 3.9 is installed correctly since I can type `$python3` and I can see python 3.9.4 loaded.

Is there a way to fix this rather than completely reinstall ubuntu?

Output of `$PATH` =

```
bash: /home/hoppingturtles/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You do not have to reinstall Ubuntu.....   `echo $PATH` will show you the path without trying to execute it, your output indicates that you tried to run the contents of $PATH, not a good plan.   git is not dependent on python so it should work if it is installed, what is the output of `which git` I expect it will be `/usr/bin/git` which is in your path and `git` should run.   Have you got the pip3 package installed?  what happens if you type  `pip3`

Comment: yes the output of `which git` is indeed `/usr/bin/git`. Running `pip3` works fine now cause I changed the shebang in `~/.local/bin/pip3` to use python 3.9. `git commit` wasn't working for me cause I was using pre-commit hooks, but committing without them works fine.

Comment: Sounds like your sorted, great

Comment: The root cause still isn't fixed though. There's still many files which would be using python 3.8, can't manually go and fix the rest. Don't know why ubuntu didn't automatically remove it.

Comment: Have you looked at pipenv? It allows you to control your python environment and have multiple versions on your system, when you run python within the environment it uses the version you have specified. Can you provide an example of a file which still fails (how does it know to run python3.8 vs just the default python3? What is in your `~/.local.bin/pip3`, the normal pip3 files don't have any specific version numbers in them, just `/usr/bin/python3` which would be 3.9 for you I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error without `pre-commit` installed (but it used to be). Some leftovers in `.git/hooks` in the local copy of the repo were apparently trying to figure out what Python is in use and caused that error.

After I've cleaned them up, everyting went fine again !